# SingleChildScrollView inside a nest of Columns

Tags: flutter, flutter-responsive-layout

I am having trouble implementing `SingleChildScrollView`. In my understanding, I can use `SingleChildScrollView` to make the widgets inside it scrollable. I have created following basic example in which I want `ElevatedButton` to be at the bottom. The remaining space is to be occupied by other widgets. And as per my understanding, if the content in other widgets exceeds the available space, the content should become scrollable because of `SingleChildScrollView`.

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Text("Some Text Here"),
        Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(color: Colors.red, height: 500),
                    Text("HELLO"),
                    Container(color: Colors.red, height: 500),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: const Text("BUTTON"),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

I have used `Expanded` above `SingleChildScrollView` so that the remaining space after `ElevatedButton` has been placed should be the scrollable area so that it has a height constraint.

How can I fix this?

> Error: ════════ Exception caught by rendering library
> ═════════════════════════════════ The following assertion was thrown
> during performLayout(): RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but
> incoming height constraints are unbounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second `Column` is getting *incoming height constraints are unbounded.*, You can wrap it with `Expanded` widget to get available space.

```dart
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Text("Some Text Here"),
        Expanded(
          child: Column( //this one 
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(color: Colors.red, height: 500),
                      Text("HELLO"),
                      Container(color: Colors.red, height: 500),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Text("BUTTON"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: can you kindly explain why does the second column have unbounded height? And is there a widget inspect with which we can see what is happening to diagnose the issue?

Comment: Top Column providing inner column infinite height(constraints) ,you can check [UI/layout/constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints)

Answer (score 1):

You only need 2 Columns. First column is for the layout in the SinglechildScrollView and the second column is to layout the SinglechildScrollView with the text at the top and the button at the bottom.

```
return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text("Some Text Here"),
                Expanded(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(color: Colors.red, height: 500),
                        Text("HELLO"),
                        Container(color: Colors.red, height: 500),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: const Text("BUTTON"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
```